# Emails with links offering job

Tags: email-spoofing

I am a designer. I have received several emails offering jobs. There is a link. I never click to links in emails. I look at the sender address and look at google to see if it could exist a real firm with that name. Most of the time I see no company. So, I assume they are malicious emails.

Is that the way to deal with this? Is there anything else I could do to protect myself without losing opportunities?

Comment: They may not be "malicious" in a technical sense, but they may be scams or other tricks to obtain your personal details.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when you dont know the source of the link, my recommendation is to use a third party service (that checks domain and uri reputation) and use it in order to get information about that link. There is online services that gives you that service. If you can not get information of the URL just basically dont click and drop the email, if a real company wants to send you a reasonable work offer they will use a proper email with valid information.

You can use the google report one [http://google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site="my](http://google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=%22my) url to analyze"